# Using Java to get Bloomberg fields over specific dates

Tags: java, bloomberg

I'm trying to pull in specific data fields from the Bloomberg Java API.  I see from the developers guide that I can pull in some fields with:

```
Request request = refDataSvc.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
request.getElement("securities").appendValue("AAPL US Equity");
request.getElement("securities").appendValue("IBM US Equity");

request.getElement("fields").appendValue("PX_LAST"); // Last Price
request.getElement("fields").appendValue("DS002"); // Description
request.getElement("fields").appendValue("VWAP_VOLUME");
session.sendRequest(request, new CorrelationID(1));
```

How can I make a call like this while getting some of the fields over a specific date range?  For example, I would like to get the: last trade price, last trade volume, the opening price for August 27th, 2012, and the VWAP volume for August 26th between 9AM and 11AM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a "HistoricalDataRequest" request:

```
Request request = refDataSvc.createRequest("HistoricalDataRequest");
```

You can then specify the start date and end date:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
request.set("startDate", startDate.toString(fmt));
request.set("endDate", endDate.toString(fmt));
```

In your case, startdate and enddate will be 27-Aug for the first request, and 26-Aug for the second.

However, I'm not sure how you can override fields (`VWAP_START_TIME` and `VWAP_END_TIME`) to restrict your VWAP to 9-11AM in a historical request, for reference data you would do smoething like the code below - it might work for historical requests too:

```
Element overridesElt = request.getElement("overrides");
Element override = overridesElt.appendElement();
override.setElement("fieldId", "VWAP_START_TIME");
override.setElement("value", "09:00:00");

override = overridesElt.appendElement();
override.setElement("fieldId", "VWAP_END_TIME");
override.setElement("value", "11:00:00");
```

Comment: So then there is no way to get the opening price for the 27th and the VWAP between 10 and 11 in the same request element?  For each data item, I will need to shoot out a new Request element?

Comment: You need either one request per day or a request over the range (26-27) and then use the relevant data. And I'm not sure you can use overloadin with more than one fields - so I would keep it simple and have one request for the first set of data for the 27th, and one request for the vwap with overriden parameters for the 26th. If you use the same session it should be fairly fast anyway. You can always ask BB Help to see if there is a better way.